# How to match two page objects text from Different Class?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, appium

I have two classes that have page objects. How to check if they match inside the method? I tried with contains and Assert.Equals and having hard time to figure out. 
obj1 = $455.00/year obj2 = $455.00/year.

```
Class A {

   AndroidFindBy(id="sdjl")
   private MobileElement obj1;

   public boolean example(String text) {
    String bodyText = obj1.getText();
    return bodyText.contains("$455.00");
}
   }

   Class B {
   AndroidFindBy(id="sjkl")
   private MobileElement obj2;


         public void exampleb() {
    String yearly = obj2.getText();
    class A v = new Class A(driver);

    Assert.assertEquals(yearly,v.example("$455.00"));
}


  }
```

Comment: The syntax is wrong (`AndroidFindBy` wouldn't compile). Disregarding that, I can't tell what you're trying to compare. There's nothing here explaining what you're comparing.

Comment: Example. If you have two object with same text. How would you do it?

Comment: Use `equals` to compare objects: `obj1.equals(obj2)`.

Comment: How would you do it inside the method ?

Answer (score 2):

**yearly**
 is a string type object and v.example("$455.00") returns either true or false , a boolean type parameter.

As far as I know, Assert.assertEquals(param1,param2) takes *homogeneous parameters*. If first one is a string, second one must also be a **string**.

Comment: What you mean second one must be a string?

Comment: The second parameter in Assert.assertEquals has to be a string type. Your class A method `public boolean example(String text)`  returns a boolean type variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check if a string contains or is equal to another string inside the `example` method.

```
class A {
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/sdjl")
    private MobileElement obj1;

    public String getObj1Value() {
        String bodyText = obj1.getText();
        return bodyText;
    }

    public void example() {
        B b = new B();

        String obj1Value = getObj1Value();
        String obj2Value = b.getObj2Value();

        boolean equals = obj1Value.equals(obj2Value);
        if (equals) {
            // ...
        }

        boolean contains = obj1Value.contains(obj2Value);
        if (contains) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class B {
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/sdjl")
    private MobileElement obj2;

    public String getObj2Value() {
        String yearly = obj2.getText();
        return yearly;
    }

    public void example() {
        A a = new A();

        String obj2Value = getObj2Value();
        String obj1Value = a.getObj1Value();

        boolean equals = obj2Value.equals(obj1Value);
        if (equals) {
            // ...
        }

        boolean contains = obj2Value.contains(obj1Value);
        if (contains) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. it says it cannot find  an element object1.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Can't locate an element by this strategy: By.id:

Comment: For `@AndroidFindBy` I could find this: https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/184 . It looks like `id` should be an id defined in an Android XML file. Please check if you have the correct ids. Also, in the example they used this format: `@AndroidFindBy(id = "android:id/sdjl")` .